# Quotients of Free pro-p groups

Tags: profinite-groups, gr.group-theory

Let $P_n$ denote the pro-$p$ completion of $F_n$ the free group  of rank $n$. Given a (abstract) group homomorphism
$$
\phi:P_n\rightarrow G
$$
where $G$ is a discrete group. Is $\phi$ continuous?

The case $G$ is finite is a Theorem of Serre and $\phi$ is continuous in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in general.  Consider for instance the case that $G$ is the same abstract group as $P_n$, but with the discrete topology.

If $G$ is *finitely generated*, the answer is yes.  See this article of Nikolov and Segal: http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3037

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and also the reference. 